# When using freed to read a large cdv, why cannot refer to the column number to read the column

Tags: r, subset, fread

When used `fread` to read a csv, for example:

```
library(data.table)
outcome4<-fread("outcome-of-care-measures.csv")
```

then I want to subset the observation if the 11th column ('Hospital 30-Day Death (Mortality) Rates from Heart Attack') is not `'Not Available'`. so I wrote below:

```
outcome5<-subset(outcome4, outcome4[,11]!="Not Available")
```

but seems like the `subset` function didn't work, the observation of outcome 5 is same with outcome4, and all the observation of the 11th column are all become to 11.

why?  if I used `read.csv` function, everything works fine.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the result of `outcome4[,11]`.

As you wrote it, `fread()` returns a data table. In turn, `outcome4[,11]` returns `11`.  And `11` is never equal to `"Not Available"`, so you get the whole table back.  You want to either use `outcome4[, 11, with = FALSE]` for the 11th column of a data table, or `data.table = FALSE` in `fread()` to return a data frame instead of a data table.

But the data table way to do this would be:

```
outcome4[<column name 11> != "Not Available"]
```

where `<column name 11>` is the unquoted name of the 11th column.

Or, change `"Not Available"` to `NA` upon reading with

```
outcome4 <- fread(file, na.strings = "Not Available")
outcome4[!is.na(<column name 11>)]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, i just ran the code you provided, it worked! May i further ask why can't use the subset() to subset the data table read by freed? Thanks!

Comment: @ShuoLiu - You can, but it's best to use the column name, not the number.  So `subset(outcome4, <column name 11> != "Not Available")` will work.  But as you can see from my answer, the regular data table method (with `[`) is easier to write anyway so why not just do that :)

Comment: i have accepted the answer, thanks for your information